# What are the basic costs of living in an Eberron campaign setting?

Tags: dnd-4e, eberron, economy

What are the basic costs of living versus wages in an Eberron campaign setting?, and are there any references in the various WotC books?

By this I mean things like ...

- how much can a guard earn ?
- what is the cost of a room for the night ?
- what's a good bribe ?

*I appreciate there are some tables in the books, but they only seem to cover the **big** cost items*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, your second question is probably the easiest to answer. I imagine that the price is the same as in the `Player's Handbook` (p.222), i.e. 5sp for a typical room and 2gp for a luxury room.

The first one is tougher. The `Eberron Player's Guide` (p.13) tells us that the lower class (of which I guess a guard belongs to) has no more than a handful of silver pieces on himself at any one time. Casting the net a bit wider, the 3.5 DMG(p.105) tells us that a laborer can earn 1sp per day, while a mercenary can earn 2sp per day. Seems likely that an ordinary guard might earn 1sp per day, while a better trained and more trusted one might earn 2sp per day.

I could have sworn that bribes were mentioned under skills somewhere in 3.5 or 4th ed, but I'll be darned if I can find the mention. However, you might try to figure it out from the above. If a guard earn 1sp/day or 3gp per month, then 3gp is a months salary, and more than he has in his pocket. 40gp is more money than he will see in a year. Whether any of those are a good bribe depends on what you want him to do, and how loyal he is to his employer.

By the way, if you follow the 3.5 DMG, then a skilled craftsperson or scribe would earn approximately 3 times as much (9gp/month), while an architect, alchemist, barrister or low-rank officer would earn somewhere between 5 and 10 times as much(15-30gp/month). These guys probably form the the lower parts of the middle class mentioned in the `Eberron Player's Guide`.

Comment: Found a paragraph in the Eberron guide referring to the upper classes [10%] (inc. paragon & epic adventurers) having ready access to 1,000's of gold, middle [30%] (inc. heroic) having access to 100's and the lower [60%] having a few gold